# Database Unloads to file

Tags: java, openjpa, oracle12c

Is there any tool/way to export tables data into a file which is inserted on that day, and this job should Run on everyday.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting specific tables that are growing rapidly every day, I would suggest implementing daily partitions on these specific tables using interval partitioning using the column that determines the record's date. This way each day's data could be easily archived using exchange partition or backed up. Also need to ensure that the partitioning column chosen is used for querying across the application to avoid scanning all partitions for SQLs and benefit from partition pruning.

If you are targeting all the application tables in your database, my suggestion does not apply. Thanks.